# simple arithmetic operation in huge amount of number c#

Tags: c#, arithmetic-expressions

I want to perform simple arithmetic operation in huge amount of number, as implement below

```
 string t = "22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222";
        //decimal number = 22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222; Integral Constant is tooo large
        //long number = 22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222; Integral Constant is tooo large

        //string ans = t / 2; // get answer in numeric form
```

How can i perform? any idea will be appreciated.

**EDIT**
I am using 3.5 .net Framework.

Comment: use BigInteger....https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger_methods(v=vs.110).aspx in System.Numerics

Comment: @user6002727 You can use long arithmetic, [read more about here](http://faculty.cse.tamu.edu/djimenez/ut/utsa/cs3343/lecture20.html)

Answer (score 4):

If you are using the.NET 4.0 you can use the [System.Numerics.BigInteger class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx).

If you are using .Net 3.5 then you can use the [Dynamic Language Runtime sources.](http://dlr.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/changeset/view/40021#694008)

You can also check the [IntX](https://github.com/devoyster/IntXLib) class

Comment: using Microsoft.Scripting.Utils; doesn't find in .netFramework3.5.. from your given Url : dlr.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/changeset/view/40021#694008

Answer (score 2):

Add reference to System.Numerics.

```
using System.Numerics;

BigInteger i = BigInteger.Parse("22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222");
```

[BigInteger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx)